# Using Handlebars.js helpers to create active elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, jquery-events

Is it possible to within a Handlebars.js helper to create elements using jQuery and attach event handler to them? I'd like to be able to create active elements using helpers.

Example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("button", function(title) {
    var button = $('<button>').text(title);
    button.click(function() {
        alert("Button " + title + " clicked.");
    });
    return $('<div>').append(button).html();
});
```

In the handlebars template I instantiate the button like this:

```
{{{button "Click Me!"}}}
```

I understand that this can not work, since the jQuery's html() function `removes' the event handler... but simply returning *button* obviously does not work either.
Handlebars helpers should be able to return DOM nodes, but this is not possible, right? I tried to return *button.get()*, but without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is create a function outside of `registerHelper` to be called onClick. So the code for that would look like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("button", function (text) {
    var button = $('<button></button>').text(text).attr('onclick', 'button_clickEvent()');
    return $('<div></div>').append(button).html();
});

var button_clickEvent = function () {
    alert("Button " + $(this).text() + " clicked.");
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work but I actually need to build the function in the helper method. Now I use [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) which handles this and a lot more stuff in a very elegant way.

Comment: @StefanK. Okay but does this answer your question?

Comment: I arrived here because I was trying to do that in Meteor. I ended up attaching the behaviour like this: `Template.myTemplate.rendered = function(){$(this.find(".selector")).toggle()};`