# Return html object from handlebars helpers

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper, registerhelper

I need to send an html object from handlebars helper as follow:

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function () {

       //Create an input object
       var inp=$('<input type="text" name="name">');

       //How to return 'inp' object without using Handlebars.SafeString
       return inp;

    });
```

I understand that I can return html string using ‘Handlebars.SafeString()’, however this is not useful to me I need to pass html object with some event assign to it.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can't template objects, only strings. you can use event attribs in your templates, but delegated events are usually better and can be bound before the template renders.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dandavis commented, using Handlebars you can't template objects, only strings. However, you can get a hold of elements after they've been added to the DOM using MutationObserver. I've created some helpers that do just this, see the `jq` helper in [post-render-bars](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145781/1630906) to a similar question for a different approach.

Here's a [**demo**](http://ekuusela.github.io/post-render-bars/example/withjquery.html#) for post-render-bars, check the example under the heading "Define a jQuery element in a template".

The helper uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), here's [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) info, see [webcomponents-lite](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) for a polyfill if needed.

Brief description for the relevant code:

[watch.js](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars/blob/master/watch.js) defines a function `forHtml(html, callback)` which triggers a callback when the given html is encountered in the DOM. It modifies the html to temporarily have a class that makes it unique.

[jQueryHelpers.js](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars/blob/master/jQueryHelpers.js) defines the helper `jq`. The helper uses the `watch.forHtml` function to watch for the block defined by the helper and calls the function you passed in to the template with the jquery element as an argument.

Here's a shortened version of the example I linked, template:

```
<p>button with a handler: {{#jq setHandler}}<button>try me</button>{{/jq}}</p>
```

And js:

```
var context = {
    setHandler: function(element) {
        element.on('click', function() { 
            alert('clicked');
        });
    }
};
var html = template(context);
// append html somewhere and the setHandler will be invoked
```

Comment: Looks cool, but feels somehow weird, can't put my finger on what it is I don't like about this way of setting handlers

Comment: Well, lots of folks prefer logic-less templates or use a completely different solution to handlebars, something like knockout.js or rivets.js. Or if you mean passing a function in the context and then using that in the helper, you don't have to do it like that. You can modify the `jq` helper to set the handler.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a fork/extension of Handlebars called DOMBars with exactly this kind of functionality in mind.

https://github.com/blakeembrey/dombars

It is deprecated by the author, but it is still usable, although you might keep in mind that using a deprecated library might have unforeseen issues down the road.

It works exactly like Handlebars, except helper function can also return DOM elements.

Your template:

```
<script id="template">
    <p>Something {{{ helper data }}}</p>
</script>
```

Code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function (text) {

   // Create an input jQuery Object and bind whatever callbacks you want to it.
   var inp = $('<input type="text" name="name">' +  text '</input>');
   
   // Return the DOM Object
   return inp.get(0);
});

template = DOMBars.compile($('#template').html())
const html = template({ data: "Something" })
```